# Can anyone suggest a detailed installation process for Ubuntu on Windows 8.2?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have never used Linux based OS and looking forward to use Ubuntu. I want guidance on installing Ubuntu with Windows 8.2 as dual boot?

Answer (score 1):

**Make a bootable USB-stick**

To create a bootable USB drive the tool that I advocate using is the Universal USB Installer from [www.pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com).

**Partition**

Windows takes up the whole of the drive when it is first installed. In order to install Ubuntu you will need to make space for it.

Press the "super key" (Windows key) on your keyboard and click the magnifying glass in the top right corner. In the search box start typing "Partitions".

Click on the option called "Create and format partitions". This will bring up the "Disk Management" screen.

To shrink the drive, right click on the "OS (C:)" volume and select "Shrink volume".

A screen will appear showing how much you can shrink the drive by. You can of course choose to shrink the drive by less than offered but never go for any more than offered as you will break your Windows 8.1 operating system if you do.

Click "Shrink" to continue.

When you are finished you will see that there is a lot of unpartitioned space. This is where Ubuntu will be installed.

**Fast Boot**

To be able to boot to your Ubuntu USB drive you will need to turn off the fast boot option.

Press the "super" key (Windows key) and then click the magnifying glass in the top right corner.
Enter "Control Panel". Click on the "Control Panel" option that appears.
When the "Control Panel" appears click on the "System and Security" heading.

Now click on "Power Options".
On the following screen click on "Choose what the power button does".

A screen will appear with the heading "Define power buttons and turn on password protection".
Scroll down until you see "Shutdown Settings".
An option should be available called "Turn on fast startup" (recommended).
Uncheck this option.

Click "Save Changes".

**Secure Boot**

In theory you don't need to turn off Secure Boot any more. In practise it is almost certain that you will.

Turning off secure boot depends on the make and model of your computer as each one has slightly different methods for turning it off.

Basically though click on the "super" key (Windows key) and then click on the power icon next to your user name.

Hold down the shift key on your keyboard and select restart computer. Keep the shift key held down until your computer reboots.

You will now have an option to go into your UEFI boot settings.

Within the UEFI settings look for the option to turn off secure boot. You don't have to switch to legacy mode and you shouldn't switch to legacy mode as this will not help your cause.

Save and exit the UEFI settings

**Install Ubuntu**

When you have turned off secure boot, save and reboot. You will probably end up back in Windows.

Now at this point to boot into Ubuntu on the USB drive I had to again hold down the shift key whilst rebooting the computer.

One of the options that appeared let me boot from the USB drive into Ubuntu 14.04 live and you should have a similar option available to you.

To begin the installation double click on the "Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" icon.

The first thing you need to do is decide which language you would like to use.

Unless you feel like the challenge isn't great enough I would choose the language that you would normally use.

Click "Next" to continue.

The next screen lets you choose which internet connection to use whilst installing Ubuntu.

Do what you want...

If you have a good broadband connection you may wish to connect to it now so that you download updates as you go. This will slow down the initial install but will save time later on as you won't have to install lots of updates.

When you click "Next" you will be shown a tick list highlighting how prepared you are for installing Ubuntu.

Click "Continue".

In the past there used to be an option on the "Installation Type" screen to install alongside Windows.

If you are installing alongside Windows 7 on a non-EFI based system then you will still have that option.

Click on "Something Else" and click "Next".

The next screen show the partition table on your computer.

Be very careful with the next few steps.

If you haven't taken that Windows backup, quit the installation, reboot and follow step 1 of this tutorial again.

You will see a large portion of free space, this is from the shrinking before. This is where I put Ubuntu.

The free space is going to be split into 3.

The first partition is for Ubuntu and will be 50 Gigabytes in size. (Examples size)

The second partition is for your home partition and stores configuration files and your personal files such as music, pictures etc.

The third partition is for swap space and is used for intensive operations and suspending the computer.

When you have found the partition with free space, click on it and press the plus symbol (+) under the disk layout.

In the size box enter 50000, select logical as the partition type, select beginning of this space and choose EXT4 as the file system.

For the mount point choose / (this means root).

Click "OK".

The disk layout screen should now show a new partition for /.

Find the large section of free space again, click on it and press the plus symbol again (+).

This time you want to set the size to be the rest of the free disk space minus 2x the amount of memory in your computer.

If you have 8 gigabytes RAM, subtract 16 gigabytes.

Again choose "Logical" as the partition type, beginning of this space for where to put the partition and EXT4 as the file system.

For the mount point choose /home.

The issue of how much swap space to use is constantly up for debate. Some people say you don't need any at all, some go for 1.5 times the amount of RAM and some say 2x.

Unless disk space is at a premium I would just go for the 2x and have done with it.

In theory if you are running lots of intensive processes such as video editing then the swap space is used to store memory that isn't currently being used (swapped) to disk. This is disk intensive and slows down your computer but it will help to prevent a crash. Swap space is also used for suspending your computer.

Now find the free disk space again, click on it and press the plus symbol. (+).

Leave the size as the rest of the free disk space, choose logical as the file system and beginning of this space as the location.

Choose "swap area" as the mount point.

The final thing to concern yourself with when partitioning is where to install the boot loader.

By default it is set to /dev/SDA on the "Installation Type" screen. This can be changed but unless you are using multiple disks you should leave this well alone.

Press "Install Now" to continue.

This worked for me.

Comment: For a guide with pics, try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 0):

Get a disk image of ubuntu (.iso file), and put it on a USB drive using win32diskimager or Unetbootin.

Then boot the the USB drive and follow the instructions given.
From there u can choose the amt. of space you want to give to each OS and also if you want some space for a swap